# Upgraded to ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS "Enable UA Infra" notification

Tags: 16.04, 18.04, server, upgrade, notification

I recently upgraded my server to Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS from 16.04.7 LTS and in Ispconfig I see notification:

> Enable UA Infra: ESM to receive additional future security updates.

See https://ubuntu.com/esm or run: `sudo ua status`

Also when I try to get update from console I see the same notification, today I updated some packages, so updates works, is this normal or I did something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When it noticed that you were out of support, it created some files in
`/var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/messages`

I'm not sure that there's anything which *removes* these files once they are no longer relevant.  But you can remove them yourself:
`sudo rm /var/lib/ubuntu-advantage/messages/*`

I think that you can also remove `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` to prevent this problem from resurfacing, I believe until the next time you let the system go out of support.  It's possible that removing the package `ubuntu-advantage-tools` is desirable.

Comment: It helped me to resolve issue with a message "E: No priority (or zero) specified for pin". As well I removed a file "/etc/apt/preferences.d/ubuntu-esm-infra",

Answer (score 1):

17 May 2021

Unfortunately, `ubuntu-advantage-tools` depends on `ubuntu-minimal`.  What this means is ubuntu considers this adware to be essential to all ubuntu systems.  You can not remove it without removing `ubuntu-minimal`, which would require also removing packages that are genuinely essential.

Ubuntu just keeps getting worse.  In my case, the hardware clock is flaky.  I therefore get these messages because the system thinks it is 2030 or something until the network time synchronization completes.  It is annoying, and simply deleting the messages won't help.

Removing `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-esm-infra.list` may work.  I'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I disabled `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/20apt-esm-hook.conf` (moving it to a backup directory) because I had problems with an Icinga monitor exiting non-zero on invoking `/usr/bin/apt-get -o 'Debug::NoLocking=true` so this should remove the notice as well as the apt hook isn't invoked any more.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I  understand, this is not a concern. This notification notify about Ubuntu Advantage Infra subscription for future security updates for another few years of LTS even after the lifespan. If you don't need this you can ignore this message may be.